# Declaring and initializing array of classes in C at runtime

Tags: c, arrays, class, unix, malloc

Okay, first I will begin with some background.
I'm working on a project for a class that involves a client and a server. They are two separate processes that communicate with each other through what we are calling request channels.

The client collects command line arguments for the number of requests, the size of the buffer for the request channels, and the number of worker threads that send the requests (-n, -b, and -w respectively).

How ever many worker threads the user wants is how many request channels I must create between the client and server.

```
RequestChannel *channel;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char *n=NULL, *b=NULL, *w=NULL;
    int num, buf, workers;
    char optchar=0;

    while((optchar=getopt(argc,argv,"n:b:w:"))!=-1)
    switch(optchar)
    {
        case 'n':
            n=optarg;
            break;
        case 'b':
            b=optarg;
            break;
        case 'w':
            w=optarg;
            break;
        case '?':
            break;
        default:
            abort();
    }
    num=atoi(n);
    buf=atoi(b);
    workers=atoi(w);

    channel=malloc(workers*sizeof(RequestChannel));

    cout << "CLIENT STARTED:" << endl;

    pid_t child_pid;
    child_pid = fork();

    if(child_pid==0)
    {
       execv("dataserver", argv);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Establishing control channel... " << flush;
        RequestChannel chan("control", RequestChannel::CLIENT_SIDE);
        cout << "done." << endl;

        for(int i=0;i<workers;i++)
            RequestChannel channel[i](chan.send_request("newthread"), RequestChannel::CLIENT_SIDE);
    }
}
```

I'm getting compile errors with the `malloc` line and I don't know what the issue is. I just want to be able to access each `RequestChannel` like `channel[i]`.

The way it is now, I receive an error saying

> invalid conversion from `void*` to `RequestChannel*`

When I replace the `sizeof(RequestChannel)` with `sizeof(*RequestChannel)`, I receive an error saying

> expected primary-expression before ')' token.

Comment: Are you using a c++ compiler to do this? That would generate the conversion error.

Comment: No. I'm using gcc, this is all C code.

Comment: You are not using pure `C`. You are clearly using `C++` because you are using `cout` and `RequestChannel::CLIENT_SIDE` (`C` does not have `::`).

Comment: @user1515928: GCC is not a C compiler. GCC is a compiler that will automatically select the language depending on the file extension (unless you specify the language explicitly). You are compiling your code as C++, not as C. Needless to add, you code cannot possibly be compiled as C, since it is obviously uses some C++-specific features. The code has a lot more problems on top of that `malloc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The malloc line is correct (but please check if it returns NULL). A C++ compiler (not C) complains since in C++ you need a cast:

```
channel = static_cast<RequestChannel *>malloc(...);
```

or, with C syntax:

```
channel = (RequestChannel*) malloc(...);
```

Comment: Actually, in C you don't need  do cast from `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the compiler error you also have logical one.

For example, you should **explicitly call constructor** for every object to create them. But you just allocate the space for them and then just use it. It will lead to very strange errors.

Also don't forget about calling destructor. Anyway, why don't you use **new** operator?

Comment: How do I allocate the memory for the array of a certain number of the classes and call the constructor for each one individually?